# Alphanumeric password validation in xsd

Tags: xml, validation, passwords, xsd

Hi I need to validate password for only alphanumeric chars( should present both alphabets and numbers from 0..9) . I mean it should contain at least one digit and remaining alphabets

The regex I use is like this :

```
     <xsd:simpleType name="PasswordType">
         <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
             <xsd:pattern value="?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]*$)^([a-zA-Z0-9]{8,20})$"/>
         </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
```

but eclipse complains the error :
 *InvalidRegex: Pattern value '?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]*$)^([a-zA-Z0-9]{8,20})$' is not a valid regular expression. The reported error was: 
 'Unexpected meta character.'.*

Could anybody help how to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what regular-expression syntax you are using, but the expression you give does not conform to the syntax defined in the XSD spec.  You say you want a string of alphanumeric characters containing at least one numeric digit.  One XSD-style regular expression that recognizes that language is

```
\p{L}*\d(\p{L}|\d)*
```

That accepts any mixture of Unicode letters and decimal digits; if you want to restrict passwords to ASCII, you could say

```
[a-zA-Z]*[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

To restrict the length to somewhere between 8 and 20, the simplest thing to do is to use the `minLength` and `maxLength` facets.

Comment: True; I understood that to be a consequence of the OP's requirements (alphanumeric, containing at least one digit; all-digit strings do satisfy that requirement).

Comment: The way I understand the question is that the password must contain both letters and digits. The initial `(?!^[0-9]*$)` excludes all-digits password.

Answer (score 0):

A missing open parenthesis?

```
<xsd:simpleType name="PasswordType"> 
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"> 
    <xsd:pattern value="(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]*$)^([a-zA-Z0-9]{8,20})$"/> 
  </xsd:restriction> 
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Comment: Not a legal XSD regular expression.

Comment: Works for me, using Visual Studio 2010 XSD validation

Comment: Interesting evidence that Visual Studio 2010 doesn't implement the XSD regular expression language correctly.

Comment: ..it implements some kind of super-set of it I guess - the question does not say what is the target validation environment, so my answer might or might not work (both yours work in VS 2010 BTW).